# Building a whole Android UI using fragments in a single activity?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-fragments

This is my first time posting so I do apologise if this is a bad question!

I am currently building an android application and have come accross a problem. The app works using bluetooth LE, and whenever an activity changes it disconnects from the remote device and reconnects to it.

This isn't great and really hinders the performance of the app. However I recently started learning about fragments and through this I could bind the service to the activity, and interact with the service through the activity using fragments changing them as needed like you would with an activity.

I understand that this isn't probably best practice but I can't think of any other way. Are there downsides to this approach I would need to consider?

**UPDATE**

I am such an idiot the reason the connection wasn't carrying over was because I had been calling connectionClose() on unbind its so stupid. Well I hope if anyone else has this problem this helps you out. I'm going to go be embarrassed somewhere else for a while.

Comment: `So my question is why would this be a bad idea?` It depends. If it is just a couple of pages, there shouldn't any problem. If several activities are involved, putting everything into one activity with multiple fragments can be a waste of resources, as well as hard to debug.

Comment: A better option would be to use the `onPause` and `onResume` methods of activities for establishing proper communication.

Comment: There would be quite a few pages involved, I'm talking more or less the whole app, it's the only way I can think that would allow me to keep the connection alive between activites

Answer (score 0):

If Bluetooth connection have nothing to do whit UI of your app you can use Intent Service. as i know intent services would not be killed by changing activity.